# Meteor AutoForm adding users to select

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I know I am close on this, but just cant seem to sort out what I am missing.

I am trying to add all users as options to a select in an autoform quickform. I was able to get it working with another collection, but when I use the same code for the users the value shows up as the _id but I cannot get the label to return.

Here is the structure of my users:

```js
{
  "_id": "s3EYXXK5N8NExHrke",
  "emails": [{
    "address": "admin@gmail.com",
    "verified": false
  }],
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Smuck",
    "licenseNumber": "1234567",
    "accountType": "administrator"
  },
  "roles": [
    "administrator"
  ],
  "createdAt": "2016-12-02T21:51:11.844Z",
  "services": {
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "$2a$10$NheMU2x/8RvcMxNHeWxbQOpHlWAQmopvk3KrMG9oo5ruTir2ARf8W"
    },
    "resume": {
      "loginTokens": [{
        "when": "2016-12-02T21:51:11.948Z",
        "hashedToken": "8PktpX6kqK6yM+LMrqRaoqXCbwYG6gdO7MH9V/Th/dI="
      }, {
        "when": "2016-12-03T03:01:06.600Z",
        "hashedToken": "ihn93xaN6rE8fvwBHZ3p8H6z0T7o7WChQoqD4dlkSpw="
      }, {
        "when": "2016-12-05T14:37:41.147Z",
        "hashedToken": "7QE7HxcmDrZPFI3Omn5c1o73pMa3XzOBj3RbquCmo6U="
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to print the firstName to the select. Here is the schema I have now:

```js
 inspector: {
   type: String,
   label: "Inspector",
   autoform: {
     firstOption: 'Choose an Inspector',
     options: function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({}, {
         sort: {
           profile: 1,
           firstName: 1
         }
       }).map(function(c) {
         return {
           label: c.firstName,
           value: c._id
         };
       });
     }
   }
 },
```

I would appreciate any help someone can offer!

Comment: But... `firstName` is under `profile`.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to Meteor how would I write that? would it be c.profile.firstName?

Comment: Nevermind lol should have tested that before I posted! Thanks for putting me in check! haha

Answer (score 0):

To tie this off it should have been:

```js
 inspector: {
   type: String,
   label: "Inspector",
   autoform: {
     firstOption: 'Choose an Inspector',
     options: function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({}, {
         sort: {
           profile: 1,
           firstName: 1
         }
       }).map(function(c) {
         return {
           label: c.profile.firstName,
           value: c._id
         };
       });
     }
   }
 },
```